# HTTP - correct error scenario response

Tags: php, http

I have two pages. `GET /register` render registration page. `POST /register` accepts two parameters `username` and `password` and handle registration.

Below I have a few error scenarios and I need to decide which one to use according to HTTP standards.

- `POST /register` - missing `username` or `password` field

  - status code 400, body contains register page with error text "missing post data".
  - status code 400, body contains error page with "400 bad request".
  - status code 303, move to `GET /register?error=1`.
- `POST /register` - username already exists

  - status code 412, body contains register page with error text "username exists".
  - status code 303, move to `GET /register?error=2`.

Comment: Use whatever status code you want. Personally, I would always make the response body text as descriptive as possible

Comment: So it's okay to render form in POST request?